# rustc generate incorrect assembly when inline

Tags: rust

I'm trying to inline some functions but the assembly code rustc generate is incorrect.

main.rs:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialOrd, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct MyType1(usize);

impl MyType1 {
    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn my_func (&self) -> usize { *self / 4096 }
}

impl core::ops::Div<usize> for MyType1 {
    type Output = usize;

    fn div (self, other: usize) -> usize { self.0 / other }
}

pub struct MyType2 {
    pub data1: MyType1,
    pub data2: usize,
}

static STATIC_VAR: MyType2 = MyType2 {
    data1: MyType1(0),
    data2: 0,
};

pub fn main () {
    let my_static_var = unsafe { &mut *(&STATIC_VAR as *const MyType2 as *mut MyType2) };

    my_static_var.data1 = MyType1(0x1a000);
    my_static_var.data2 = my_static_var.data1.my_func ();
}
```

Assembly code of main function:

```
; var int64_t var_10h @ rsp+0x8
│           ; var int64_t var_8h @ rsp+0x10
│           0x00004300      4883ec18       sub rsp, 0x18
│           0x00004304      31c0           xor eax, eax
│           0x00004306      89c7           mov edi, eax
│           0x00004308      48c744241000.  mov qword [var_8h], 0x1a000 ; [0x1a000:8]=0xd5e9fffffa7b84
│           0x00004311      488b4c2410     mov rcx, qword [var_8h]
│           0x00004316      48890d131d02.  mov qword [obj.main::STATIC_VAR::h1456afe986ab6f8a], rcx ; [0x26030:8]=0
│           0x0000431d      be00100000     mov esi, 0x1000
│           0x00004322      e889ffffff     call sym <main::MyType1 as core::ops::arith::Div<usize>>::div::he4115301add5ef17 ; sym._main::MyType1_as_core::ops::arith::Div_usize__::div::he4115301add5ef17
│           0x00004327      4889442408     mov qword [var_10h], rax
│           0x0000432c      488b442408     mov rax, qword [var_10h]
│           0x00004331      488905001d02.  mov qword [0x00026038], rax ; [0x26038:8]=0
│           0x00004338      4883c418       add rsp, 0x18
└           0x0000433c      c3             ret
```

As you can see, main call MyType1::Div function with 2 params, 0 and 0x1000, with not correct. It should be *self/4096.

build command: `rustc main.rs`

rustc --version: `rustc 1.43.1 (8d69840ab 2020-05-04)`

Comment: You invoke undefined behaviour, at this point, anything can happen and nothing can be expected. Also, Rust allow compiler to do any strange optimisation that it can if this respect Rust rules.

Comment: You're never allowed to cast an immutable reference into a mutable one, as you do on the first line of `main`. So your entire program is undefined behavior and the compiler can emit whatever assembly it wants.

Comment: (also, 0x1000 is 4096... so asm is correct)

Comment: 2rd param is correct, what wrong is the first param, it should not be 0

Comment: Do I allow to make immutable ref from mutable static? @Frxstrem

Comment: first param is loaded here `mov qword [var_8h], 0x1a000 ;` again I don't see the problem. Both with your UB (with a obvious fix) and without give the correct result. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7783d558d85a140bf654c03e0b96cac https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b3283069bc72d87d91e801b14214326c

Comment: No, it loaded here: xor eax, eax; mov edi eax

Comment: I agree about UB. But I still surprise how UB can cause compiler generate incorrect code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Frxstrem and @Stargateur point out. Making mutable ref from immutable is undefined behavior and anything can go wrong. So I need to make STATIC_VAR mutable:

```
static mut STATIC_VAR: MyType2 = MyType2 {
    data1: MyType1(0),
    data2: 0,
};
```

and change the line:

`let my_static_var = unsafe { &mut *(&STATIC_VAR as *const MyType2 as *mut MyType2) };`

to:

`let my_static_var = unsafe { &mut STATIC_VAR };`